# HiddenField value modified by javascript is not posted back

Tags: javascript, postback

This is weird, but I've been using this method all over my code: I have dropdown lists that I populate client-side, using callbacks and because of this I'm unable to access their selected values from code behind and using a hidden field to store selected value in it. I had no problem retrieving the hidden field's value on postback, but all of a sudden it stopped working and is always blank, even when the value on client side is present.
Any thoughts?

P.S. I'm not setting or resetting hidden fields on postback.

Comment: It sounds like it should work - can you post a minimal example of the code which causes the problem?

Comment: aspx: <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTechID" runat="server" />
js: $("#<%=hfTechID.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
aspx.cs: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfTechID.Value)) { }

I do check for value on button click before postback and it is there. Not really sure what might be causing this

Comment: Yet the same exact code works on different page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if someone wonders what's wrong: it seems there's something related to jQuery.
The thing is that DropDownLists and the hidden field, along with the button that causes postback are inside a jQuery UI dialog that is initiated on page load without opening and appended to the form. Besides this dialog i'm initializin another one and also appending to the form, but for some reason the first appended dialog exibits the weird behavior when postback works, but hidden field does not retain the value. If i don't append the second dialog to the form, everything works as expected. Can't really tell what might appending the second dialog be doing that is causing this weird behavior.

P.S if i reverse the order in which those two dialog boxes are appended, it works just fine... Weird!

Comment: Had the same problem. As I moved all hidden fields out of the dialog it started working.

Comment: I had the same problem as well.  I believe the root cause is that jQueryUI attaches dialogs to the BODY tag not the FORM tag, where .Net needs it to be. I solved it by detaching the jQueryUI dialog and overlay and re-attaching them to the form on the dialog's open handler:

Comment: open: function (event, ui) {
                    var $up = $('[id$=MainUpdatePanel]');
                    var $firstForm = $('form:first');
                    if ($up.length) {
                        $up.append($('.ui-dialog, .ui-widget-overlay').detach());
                    }
                    else {
                        $firstForm.append($('.ui-dialog, .ui-widget-overlay').detach());
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET?

When the values are added dynamically the backend has no clue. You need to use [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) to get the values posted back just like oldschool ASP days.