# jQuery update of asp:HiddenField fails to be persisted across postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, sitecore

I have a sublayout in sitecore (which is an ascx control) which contains a hidden field and an image map. Depending on the area of the image map which is clicked, I want to set the value of the hidden field, then initiate a postback to the server.

My markup is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetRegion(regionName) {
    $('#<%=hdnRegion.ClientID%>').val(regionName);
    __doPostBack('<%=lnkRedirectButton.UniqueID%>', '');
}
</script>

<img src="/Images/Interface/Map-Background.png" usemap="#regionMapView" class="map" />
<map id="regionMapView" name="regionMapView">
    <area id="x" href="javascript:SetRegion('x')" shape="poly" coords=",,,," />
    <area id="y" href="javascript:SetRegion('y')" shape="poly" coords=",,,," />
    <area id="z" href="javascript:SetRegion('z')" shape="poly" coords=",,,," />
</map>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRegion" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRedirectButton" onclick="lnkRedirectButton_Click" runat="server" />
```

and my code-behind is as follows:

```
    protected void lnkRedirectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string region = hdnRegion.Value; //at this point, I expect hdnRegion.Value to be "x" "y" or "z" but it's always coming back empty :-(
        //do stuff...
    }
```

I added the dummy LinkButton to use as a hook for the postback (to create a code-behind method to handle the postback).

I've tried this code in a stand-alone webapplication and it seems to work fine, so I'm wondering if there is something going on with sitecore which is messing up the hidden field's value during the postback process?

To clarify;  the postback event is being fired and handled on the server ok and I've used alert() in javascript to confirm that the hidden field value was being set correctly.

**Edit:**
Retagged question to include jquery-ui tag.
This issue seems to be related to the fact that all of this is happening inside of a div which is displayed using $().dialog() method in the jQuery UI library...

Comment: Do you have sublayout caching on your sublayout? That would affect the HTML that gets outputted to the page.

Comment: Hi, no I don't. That's reminded me though, in this case the control is put directly onto my layout aspx and isn't used as a sublayout.

Comment: So if you hard-code the rendered ID into the `__doPostBack()` function does it work or no?

Comment: I'll give that a go, but my problem isn't really to do with initiating the postback correctly; it's with the hidden field's value being lost somewhere during the postback process.

Comment: Please just confirm yes or no if that works. It seems like based on the behavior thus far that it will not work, but I'm still curious...

Comment: +1, good question. There's a magic setting called AutomaticDataBind, obviously it affects the data binding components, like Repeater, but I recall couple of cases when relatively unrelated stuff was affected by this setting being true or false when it should have been the opposite... Anyway, I'm almost sure it has nothing to do with the current case, but you might want to check to make sure...

Comment: @Mark Ursino I tried hard-coding the clientId into the __doPostBack function and still it didin't work.

Comment: I would take a step-by-step approach with this. First, as you did, hard code the ID into the JS postback call and use the VS debugger to see if `lnkRedirectButton_Click()` is even being called. If not then it appears the ID being passed into the postback it not causing the LinkButton click. If the debugger does catch the code and you find it does run your click method then thr next step if to play with how to access the value of the HiddenField. Break it down into small steps to see at which step its actually not working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit, this issue is related to the fact that the hidden field (and everything else) is inside a div which is manipulated using the jQuery UI dialog method to create a popup window.

I found this question ([HiddenField value modified by javascript is not posted back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705085/hiddenfield-value-modified-by-javascript-is-not-posted-back))
which gave me the answer and involves adding a single line of code to the open: callback in the dialog methods constructor.

My JavaScript code for opening the dialog was modified as follows:

```
$('#MyDialog').dialog({
    closeOnEscape: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); //this line sorted everything!
    }
});
```

To quote [DanaBenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144612/danabenson)  "I believe the root cause is that jQueryUI attaches dialogs to the BODY tag not the FORM tag, where .Net needs it to be."

Comment: Argh, thank you - I've just been trying to figure out why my jQuery UI dialog wasn't posting back checkbox fields.

Comment: Just in case it doesn't work for somebody, this could be useful: `$("#divName").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));`

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass the value back as a postback parameter instead of a hidden field value, since you are just doing an immediate postback?

Comment: Ah good idea. Would I just create an invisible textbox, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This is just the second parameter in the __doPostBack() method, I believe.  You should just be able to pass the regionName instead of the empty string.  Then access it using Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"].  Haven't tried this, so I may be off.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I'll give it a go on Monday!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ClientID instead of UniqueID

__doPostBack('<%=lnkRedirectButton.ClientID%>', '');

Comment: Did _you_ try this? If I use ClientID instead of UniqueID, the page will postback but my lnkRedirectButton_Click event handler method does not get called.

Comment: I use the same method with ClientID. I don't know why it didn't work for you.